# Can I eager load data within a template?

Tags: matrix

I have a Matrix field with a single block type and within that, a number of fields that I need to pull out:

```
{% for roomContent in hotelEntry.roomsAvailable %}
    {% if roomContent.code == room.roomTypeCode %}
        <p>room code = {{ roomContent.code }}<br>
            description = {{ roomContent.description }}<br>
            {% for image in roomContent.images %}
                <img src="{{ image.url }}" alt="{{ roomContent.description }}" height="50">
            {% endfor %}
        </p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I am doing this on a listing page where there are around 60 entries, so this is resulting in a lot of calls to the DB.

Is there a way I can eager load all of the data for all of the entries outside of this loop so I'm not recursively calling for data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't with any build in Craft functions. I've added [a feature request for this on Crafts feedback site](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/7203963-eager-loading-of-field-relations-in-templates).

What you can do for now is to use Mike Peppers excellent Plugin "Fetch" which pre-fetch relations for you.

Ser here https://github.com/mdcpepper/fetch